# Content is not visible when clicking on menu pages - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I run a website - https://travelando.info/ - and I am having a hard time putting content on some pages. If you click on the menu EUROPE or UNITED STATES, the pages are empty. If you click on specific countries, the content is there. How to make sure that everything that is posted on the pages under the respective menu, gets also published on the page of the menu itself?

Thanks for your help!

I tried reordering the menus in the backend but it did not help.

Comment: You should be able to access to https://travelando.info/category/europe/ instead to https://travelando.info/europe/. However, if you need to have content for yhttps://travelando.info/europe/, you could create custom template and custom query under this, to get all posts from category europe

Answer (score 0):

Note the top-level menu item is linking to https://travelando.info/europe/
Your category page is located under https://travelando.info/category/europe/

From Admin Dashboard > Menus > [your menu] - either add a custom link directing to ../category/europe/ or add the "Europe" category, found under "Categories"

Comment: thank you so much! I could solve the problem thanks to your help!